# User permission control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a WPF application that has some permission restrictions, so there are screens that only administrators can see and some features only allowed to them.

Currently i'm checking the permission acess level on the constructor method of every screen with a User object flow through the application. But I can't help to think that there must be a more intelligent and proper way to do that.

Is it possible to have some kind of PermissionHandler class to do the verification and set what the user can and can not do due to his permission level?

Thanks in advence.

Comment: Are you managing the storage of users yourself, your not using any Membership provider?

Comment: I think what you want to do is put the security stuff in the business logic tier instead of the UI, http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/197977/38951

Comment: That's exacly what I wanna do. I think it's going to take me a little research to fully understand but it's a great start! I'd love to check your asnwer as correct if you wanna post it, @JeremyThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is put the security stuff in the business logic tier instead of the UI.

I'm not sure on your projects architecture/design pattern but this QA is a good start to moving the security logic into a Controller or a ViewModel: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/197977/38951

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. You can either use the Singleton pattern or a static class for that. Something like that (pseudo code):

```
public static class PermissionHandler
{
    public static User {get;set;}
    public static Login(string username, string password)
    {
        //set User here 
    }
}
```

Than you can even bind to `User.Claims` or make a method on `PermissionHandler` to get the permission right. Anyways, if you are just using this to show/hide your controls your application can get easily hacked by using for example Snoop. So if you really need "protect" the usage of some features you should make the check in the business logic or server-side ( if you have one).

If you go for server side I highly recommend you to use a token service. For example https://jwt.io/ or [ADFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services). There are of course tons of others, but this will take too long for this QA-format...